# I have created an SSL/TLS certificate for localhost for my backend ASP.NET Core web api, can I share it with my front-end Angular app?

Tags: angular, ssl, asp.net-core, certificate, certificate-authority

I have a backend server running in ASP.NET Core. There I have generated an SSL/TLS certificate and it was automatically added to the trusted CA on my machine. I want to serve my angular app over SSL/TLS also, for local development. Angular front end is running on localhost as well just a different port. Do I have to create a different certificate for my Angular app since it is on a different port? (Does the difference in port matter? Is it considered a different domain at that point?). If I can share it, how would I go about doing it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for the certificate it doens't make a difference regarding the port.   you just secure your resources in your angular and asp.net with this certificate.  make sure all the services you try to connect to are on https otherwise your browser will block the outgoing request.   the only place where the port is of importance would be in the security policies (content security policies) against  XSRF, XSS, ...

just add something like the following in package.json:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "ng serve --ssl --ssl-key c:\\certificates\\localhost.key  --ssl-cert c:\\certificates\\localhost.crt --host 0.0.0.0"
```

note: `--host 0.0.0.0` is only needed if you want to access the dev server from outside localhost...

In your browser/dev machine add it to the trusted CA.  here's a reference on how to do it for chrome:

https://support.securly.com/hc/en-us/articles/206081828-How-to-manually-install-the-Securly-SSL-certificate-in-Chrome

Comment: I have created my own key and certificate. The problem is that I now have two localhost certificates. One for ASP.NET Core and one I created myself for all purposes. Chrome requires your certificates to have the "Subject Alternative Name" present. When I launch angular it goes to https ://local... this still brings up the "Your connection is not private" warning. When I inspect chrome manage certs, I only see the localhost cert from asp.net core not one I just created. Importing the certificate does not seem to be actually importing it into the browser. This is where I am stuck.

Comment: what about the following: https://support.securly.com/hc/en-us/articles/206081828-How-to-manually-install-the-Securly-SSL-certificate-in-Chrome

Comment: if you add the certificate for localhost it works.  it works.  in essence its just an indicator nothing more.  your traffic is encrypted anyway.

Comment: What solved the issue for me was the fact that I had to import the created certificate into the 'Trusted Root Certificate Authorities' in chrome. This combined with adding 'sslKey: <name.key>' 'sslCert: <name.cert> ' in angular.json file under the serve > options file and with running ng serve --ssl has done the trick for me.

Comment: thats what was described in the anser and the document in the comments...  can you please accept my answers and comments.

Comment: the angular.json way is an alternative as  putting it as command-line  parameters.